# Creating Unified Groups using Unified API not creating One Drive

Tags: office365, office365api

Using the Unifed API to create Unified Groups (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/groups-rest-operations#CreateAGroup).

Up until yesterday this seemed to be working fine.  After waiting an hour we were able to add members, documents, etc via code with no issues.  As of yesterday our code to add documents to the groups OneDrive started failing.

Now when creating a group via the API (waiting an hour or more) when going into O365 -> Mail selecting the group and then selecting files you get a screen saying "We're setting up OneDrive for the new group."

After that our code to upload documents is working fine.  It appears the Post to create groups (POST https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/{tenant}/groups) isn't setting up the groups OneDrive.  This used to work.

Do we now need to set up the groups OneDrive separately, is there a property in the json that is passed over in the post that needs to be set?

Answer (score 0):

We are updating the group creation pipeline to support instant-on. As a temporal work around please make sure that your app, in addition to having Groups.ReadWite.All permission scope, it also has Sites.ReadWrite.All.

Comment: Could I get a little more information about what you mean by "Groups.ReadWite.All permission scope, it also has Sites.ReadWrite.All."  Are those properties we set in the Group json object when posting to create the group?

Comment: In the Azure Management portal when you select the permission scopes that you application requires, please select "Read and write all groups" and "Edit or delete items in all site collections". Again this is a temporary workaround, in the long run only "Read and write all groups" will be required to create groups and all of its content (conversations, calendar, files, etc)